# Big Oh rules - How to argue in case of negative base

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

Let us say you have a function $C_n = (-2)^n + 2^n$.
It would seem that it would be correct to assume that the running time of this algorithm would be $O(2^n)$.
However, how would I go about arguing this? The rule I had in mind would be that $a^n$ is $O(b^n)$ if $0 < a \leq b$. But since $a$ is $< 0$, this rule cannot be applied. How would one argue the relevancy of the roots in cases like this, where the specific conditions do not hold up?

Comment: You mean $(-2)^n$ or $-(2^{n})$ in your function $C(n)$?

Comment: I do mean that the root itself is negative. (-2)^n

Comment: What algorithm?

Comment: Algorithms usually have strictly positive running times.

Answer (score 1):

If $C_n = -2^n + 2^n$, then this just simplifies to $C_n = 0$, so I assume that you mean $C_n = (-2)^n + 2^n$. Then:

$$
C_n \le |-2|^n + 2^n = 2^{n+1} = O(2^n).
$$

Comment: The inequality doesn't work for odd n

Comment: For odd n, C(n)=0 < 2^n. Therefore C(n)=O(2^n), but C(n)!=\Omega(2^n)

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, I was referring to the lower bound of C(n) which is true only for even n

Comment: That's in $\Theta(3^n)$.  For even $n$ you get $C_n = -0.06 \cdot 3^n + 0.28 \cdot 3^n = 0.22 \cdot 3^n$. For odd $n$ you get $C_n = 0.06 \cdot 3^n + 0.28 \cdot 3^n = 0.34 \cdot 3^n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The real example is $C_n = -0.06*(-3)^n + 0.28*3^n$.
I had the same arguments as you, that when n was odd, $C_n = 0.34*3^n$, and thus the upper bound would be $O(3^n)$.
And for even it would be $C_n = 0.22*3^n$, which would also give an upper bound of O(3^n). However the assignment asked us to argue which root was the significant one, which was only possible by taking the absolute value of |-3|, for which it should be possible to argue that $ 0 < |-3| <= 3|.$

Comment: @vonbrand thanks for fixing the typo in big-oh notation!

Answer (score 0):

> Let us say you have a function $C_n = (-2)^n + 2^n$. It would seem that it would be correct to assume that the running time of this algorithm would be $O(2^n)$.

You mention *the running time of this algorithm*, but the text doesn't mention any algorithm. *Asymptotic analysis is about real-valued functions.* It has nothing to do with algorithms. Asymptotic analysis can be used to understand the running time of algorithms, but it exists separately of algorithms. Moreover, it is often applied outside the realm of algorithms. For example, the number of primes in the interval $1,\ldots,n$ is $\Theta(n/\log n)$ (the prime number theorem); $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n$ (Stirling's approximation); and so on.

Furthermore, in most reasonable computation models, $C_n$ is not the running time of any algorithm. Indeed, $C_1 = 0$ whereas $C_2 = 8$. This suggests that the algorithm is told the length of the input, and based on that, it can decided to immediately halt when $n = 1$ (more generally, when $n$ is odd), and to do some computation when $n = 2$ (more generally, when $n$ is even). The algorithm must be told the length of the input, since without observing the input, it cannot tell whether $n=1$ or $n=2$ in zero time units.

Algorithms which depend arbitrarily on the length of the input do exist and are being studied (they are called *non-uniform* algorithms), but actual algorithms implemented on a computer are typically not of this kind.

> However, how would I go about arguing this?

You would use the definition. Here is one popular definition of big O notation: if $f,g\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}_+$ (where $\mathbb{R}_+$ stands for the *non-negative* real numbers) then we say that $f(n) = O(g(n))$ if there exist $M,N>0$ such that $f(n) \leq Mg(n)$ for all $n \geq N$. Using this definition, we can easily see that $C_n = O(2^n)$: take $M=2$ and arbitrary $N$.